# Problem receiving data from bluetooth at very high speeds

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm using the flutter_bluetooth_serial 0.4.0 package, it has a listen function that receives a function that returns the reading of the sending of a string (List Uint8), but for my case I need to carry out the communication at a very high speed, and when that it happens it does not understand where the end of a string is and it joins it until it overflows with 230 bytes and shows it as if it were a single string, I tried to solve this in several ways, but I can only receive the complete string (18 bytes) when I reduce the transmission speed, I've tried using some characters like '\n', to see if it understands where a string ends and another begins, but I wasn't successful either. If I could read character by character for me it would also solve it, because the messages have a sending pattern.
Do you have an idea how I could be solving this? Some package that works better than this one for this purpose or some way to determine where the end of the string is. I thank!

Here is the code snippet I get the data:

```
    _dataSubscription = connection.input!.listen(_onDataReceived);

   void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
    print('Data incoming: ${ascii.decode(data)}');  

    // Allocate buffer for parsed data
    var backspacesCounter = 0;

    for (var byte in data) {
      if (byte == 8 || byte == 127) backspacesCounter++;
    }

    var buffer = Uint8List(data.length - backspacesCounter);
    var bufferIndex = buffer.length;

    // Apply backspace control character
    backspacesCounter = 0;
    for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data[i] == 8 || data[i] == 127) {
        backspacesCounter++;
      } else {
        if (backspacesCounter > 0) {
          backspacesCounter--;
        } else {
          buffer[--bufferIndex] = data[i];
        }
      }
      // print(backspacesCounter);
      // print(buffer);
      // print(bufferIndex);
    }
```

I've tried using some characters like '\n', to see if it understands where a string ends and another begins, read character per character, but doesn't have function to do this.

Comment: is `connection.input` a `Stream`?

Comment: ok, I found it is a `Stream`, so: `connection.input!.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: $line'))`

Comment: utf8.decoder is giving The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'

Comment: I tried to use ascii.decoder which really would be suitable and is returning: The argument type 'AsciiDecoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'

Comment: add `cast<List<int>>()` before the first `transform` so it looks: `connection.input!.cast<List<int>>().transform(...`

Comment: I managed to solve it!!! If you want to post it for me to approve, I just adapted what you sent, and it worked great.

       _dataSubscription = connection.input!
           .map(ascii.decode)
           .transform(const LineSplitter())
           .listen((line) => print('line: $line'));